# How to open SQLite database while debugging in VS 2019 C# UWP

Tags: c#, sqlite, debugging, uwp, visual-studio-2019

I've read a ton of articles on this topic but still not able to overcome the problem.
Standard code to open a database:

```
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;
    
string _dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "orders.db");
            using (SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection($"Filename={_dbPath}"))
        {
         db.Open();
        etc.
        }
```

The system doesn't produce any error and the databse has Open state. But it's not my database! It seems the system open new empty database (I can create tables, isert/read records there) instead.

Can anybody explain me what I should do to be able to work with my existing database?

I set Mode=ReadWrite - now the new database is not created and produces the error: cannot open db

The database is located in the project root directory.

Comment: It looks to me as if the database connection is targeting a local application folder, this may change with a debug build. What is the value of `_dbPath`?

Comment: _dbPath = "C:\\Users\\igor\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\788c53c6-12c2-4b62-b914-769704a39714_b7nycz63rfkrt\\LocalState\\orders.db"

Comment: The project root directory is not the `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`. Could you please check where the DB file is? If the path points to the local folder, please make sure the DB file is in the local folder, not the root directory.